# Find the volume of the body that is limited by the plane given in the spherical coordinates

Tags: volume, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume of the body that is limited by the plane given in the spherical coordinates at
$$r=4-2\cos\varphi$$
where $\varphi$ is the azimuth.

I don't see what they are asking for in this question. How do I do it, and what answer do we get?

Comment: If you were to plot all points that have $(r,\theta,\phi)$ which satisfy the above, you would get a closed surface (as $R(\phi) = R(\phi + 2\pi)$, and you would need to find the volume enclosed by it

Comment: In the plane we have *polar* coordinates, and the area enclosed by the curve $\rho(\theta)=4-2\cos(\theta)$ is given by $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(4-2\cos\theta\right)^2\,d\theta=18\pi$.

Comment: I've already tried this, but the answer isn't right.

Comment: Assuming we want to compute the enclosed area, it *is* $18\pi$. The curve is a smooth deformed circle with diameter $\approx 8$.

Comment: We can test our answer in an editor, and 18$pi$ isnt correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the cross-section of the solid at a constant azimuth $\varphi$ is a semicircle, since the polar angle $\theta$ takes no part in the equation. This means that we can integrate to find the volume:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{4-2\cos\varphi}1\cdot r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\varphi$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{(4-2\cos\varphi)^3}3\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2(4-2\cos\varphi)^3}3\,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{16}3\int_0^{2\pi}(2-\cos\varphi)^3\,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{16}3\int_0^{2\pi}(8-12\cos \varphi+6\cos^2\varphi-\cos^3\varphi)\,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{16}3\int_0^{2\pi}\left(8-12\cos\varphi+3(1+\cos2\varphi)-\frac14(3\cos\varphi+\cos3\varphi)\right)\,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{16}3\int_0^{2\pi}\left(11-\frac{51}4\cos\varphi+3\cos2\varphi-\frac14\cos3\varphi\right)\,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{16}3\left[11\varphi-\frac{51}4\sin\varphi+\frac32\sin2\varphi-\frac1{12}\sin3\varphi\right]_0^{2\pi}=\frac{16}3(22\pi)=\frac{352\pi}3$$